# How to scrape images and save to a file

Tags: python, image, screen-scraping

I'm not sure how to save scraped images to a file on my desktop.

I'm trying to download images from the site listed in the code, but I only know the basics like importing BeautifulSoup and Request. I don't understand what everything means.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as request


folder = r'C:\Users\rlook\Desktop\scrape' + '\\'
url = "https://www.butterfliesofamerica.com/t/Phocides_belus_a.htm"
response = request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
for res in soup.findAll('img')
```

I can follow some code on other sites, but can't make it work for my purposes.`enter code here`

```
from urllib.request as request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

folder = r'C:\Users\rlook\Desktop\scrape' + '\\'
URL ='https://www.butterfliesofamerica.com/t/Phocides_belus_a.htm'
response = request.urlopen(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser') 

iconTable = soup.find('a', {'class' : 'y'})

request.urlretrieve(icon.img['src'], folder + icon.img['alt'] + '.jpg')
```

Comment: Can you post any code that you have tried to download images and maybe give us a starting point to help you out?

Comment: I added the code below the original post

Comment: It's possible to get and save all the thumbnails on that page, but they don't have the `alt` attribute; for example: <img src="../thumbnails/Eudaminae/Phocides_belus_M_CR_Prov_San_Jose_Hacienda_el_Rodeo_720m_28-IX-07_3.jpg" width="200"/></a>.

Comment: If I just use request.urlretrieve(iconTable.img['src'], folder + '.jpg') it blows up.  urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Comment: I don't see the connection between these two things. Can you give an example of `icon.img['alt']`?

Comment: That line was one that I copied in error from somewhere else. I guess the goal is just to scrape images from https://www.butterfliesofamerica.com/t/Phocides_belus_a.htm and save them to a folder on my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I used requests and beautifulsoup (as well as re and shutil) to get the full size image, instead of just the thumbnail. You must `pip install requests` and `pip install bs4` in the command line for this solution to work.

## Code

```py
import requests, re, shutil
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36',
}
base_url = 'https://www.butterfliesofamerica.com'
all_imgs = requests.get(base_url + '/t/Phocides_belus_a.htm', headers=headers)
parsed_imgs = BeautifulSoup(all_imgs.text, 'html.parser')

img_hrefs = [img['href'] for img in parsed_imgs.find_all('a', class_='y')]
for img_href in img_hrefs:
    real_img_href = img_href.replace('..', base_url)
    image_page = requests.get(real_img_href, headers=headers)

    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(image_page.text, 'html.parser')
    source_image = page_soup.find('img')['src']
    img_name = re.search(r'/([\w\-\.]+?\.(?:jpg|JPG))', source_image).group(1)

    img = requests.get(base_url + source_image, stream=True, headers=headers)
    with open(img_name, 'wb') as img_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(img.raw, img_file)
        print(img_name, ' found')
```